# Having problems with iconv not transliterating any more

Tags: php, iconv

This code used to work and transliterate accented characters to 7-bit ASCII:

```php
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US_POSIX.UTF-8');
    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'US-ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'Jalapeño Café');
```

But instead of `Jalapeno Cafe`, it's now outputting `Jalapeo Caf`.

I can see `en_US_POSIX` in the list of locales on the server.

The PHP version is 7.4.10.

The problem occurred before and after much experimentation I was able to find the locale and iconv parameters to fix it, but now it's not working. Any recommendations on what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I inspect the return value of `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US_POSIX.UTF-8')` I get `false`, which means there was an error. So if that appeared to work in the past, I'm betting there was something else kicking in before it.

You should be able to just use `en_US` for the locale.

```php
if(false === setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US')){
    throw new \RuntimeException('Could not change the locale');
}

echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'Jalapeño Café');

// Jalapeno Cafe
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/AVQhU

Comment: Thank you for checking it out. Confirmed it is a problem at the server level. All the locales are failing. Issue has been escalated.

Comment: After some experimenting found one locale which works on our installation `C.UTF-8`.